# How do I calculate the number of combinations where a specified number of elements are not repeated?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

My maths is very rusty.  I am looking to calculate how many unique combinations I can draw from a given set of names.

I understand the formula $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r)!}$ will give me the number of unique combinations of $r$ elements from the set with $n$ elements, where all combinations will contain at least $1$ different element.

What if I wanted to specify the minimum number of elements that had to be different?

For example, the number of combinations of $6$ names I could draw from $36$ names = $\frac{36!}{30!\,6!}=1,947,792$

Every combination would have at least 1 name different to every other combination. How do I work out the number of combinations if I wanted at least 2 or 3 names in every combination to be different.

Names in the set are unique and can't be repeated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure but may be the Polard Rho algorithm may help in some sense:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Comment: Just to clarify - are you asking for how many combinations can be constructed when each combination can only share so many names, such as the classic case of 7 choose 3 with no pairs repeating: {123,145,167,246,257,347,356} (also known as the Fano plane)?

Comment: This is confused. The combinations your formula counts are combinations _without repetition_: **all** of the elements in the selection must be different. (If you wanted to allow the same element to appear more than once in a combination, then the formula would have to be $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!r!}$, but you say "Names in the set are unique and can't be repeated".) But then what do you mean by "if I wanted at least 2 or 3 names in every combination to be different"? All names already must be different.

Comment: One possible interpretation is that if you have chosen one cobination, you want other combinations to differ in at last 2 places. But that is not well defined, it is like asking "How many people live in this country if one only counts those that live at least 5 km apart?", it just insn't clear about which collection exactly you are talking.

Comment: Sorry to confuse everybody. I did say I was rusty!

@GlenO - yes, i wanted to calculate all sets of 6 names where no more than a given number of names are the same.

In the example I attempted to provide I meant how many sets of 6 names can I draw from 36 names where no more than 4 names are the same in any two sets.

Comment: Thank you to everybody - I had supposed this would be something you could calculate - it seems from the comments it is not so straight-forward.

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon I think the main point here is that what you present as a counting problem ("work out the number of combinations") is in fact an _optimisation problem_: find the largest possible set of combinations that meet your criterion. The criterion does not specify a single set oc combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the maximum number of combinations under such a restriction is not known in any closed-form manner. The topic of constructing combinations like this is the topic of Block Design. There is a theoretical maximum, but there's no guarantee that the maximum can be achieved for any particular number of chosen elements or number of elements available.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between each of your sets of six names would be useful. Each of your sets of six names would be considered a string of length $n=6$ from an alphabet set with $q=36$ elements.

By specifying a minimum number of elements to be different, you are specifying the minimum Hamming distance $d$ between each of the strings. There is then an upper bound to the number of possible strings that are at least $d$ apart from each other, given by the [Hamming Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound), but it is not always achievable, as mentioned by Glen.